# output the last value of the function

Tags: javascript, slider, console.log

I have a written slider function that, when clicked, displays all values in the console

```js
function outputUpdate(vol) {
  let output = document.querySelector('#volume');
  output.value = vol;

  output.style.left = vol - 20 + 'px';
  if (output.value > 9) {
    output.style.left = vol - 30 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 99) {
    output.style.left = vol - 40 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 240) {
    output.style.left = vol - 45 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 430) {
    output.style.left = vol - 50 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 470) {
    output.style.left = vol - 55 + 'px';
  }
  console.log(vol)
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <output for="fader" id="volume">0</output>
  <input type="range" id="fader" min="0" max="600" value="0" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
</div>
```

but I need to get only the last value from the console

I tried to write a loop inside the function, but it gives me all the values

```js
      for(i= 0; i< output.value; i++){
             vol1 = vol;
        }
        console.log(vol1)
```

Current output:
[image: output]
added a picture, I need to get only the final value in the console (i.e. in this case 46) and not all values

Comment: What would the expected "last value" be?

Comment: you can use a loop but add a condition to print only when you reach the last index

Comment: think this way -- if vol is 490, all of your conditions would be true. try to think a way to control this behaviour :)

Comment: @pink added a picture

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @pink I set the value with the slider and the picture shows that it stopped at 46, I only need to display 46 in the console

Comment: There's no way to delete previous logs. The next best thing you could do is `console.clear()` before each log.

Comment: You can have something like a timer, because that's probably the only way to "know" when you've stopped moving the slider.

Comment: Have you tried using ```switch``` case?

Comment: @Nikkkshit, no, now read about event keyup

Comment: If you only want one branch of your if to trigger, use else ifs, and order your statements so you check the least likely thing first (ie, if the value > 470 its definitely > 9, so do the test for > 470 first)

Comment: @Марта, could you please add your ```html``` code as well?

Comment: Use ```console.clear();```, as @pink suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From @Pointy's suggestion.
- We have added property to `outputUpdate`, function. F.Y.I, `function` is an object in javascript so we can add as many properties as we want, here we have created `timerId` property to store id, initialized it with default value `0`, to avoid `TypeError`, because `clearTimeout()` function expects, valid Id.

```js
function outputUpdate(vol) {
  let output = document.querySelector('#volume');
  output.value = vol;
  output.style.left = vol - 20 + 'px';
  if (output.value > 9) {
    output.style.left = vol - 30 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 99) {
    output.style.left = vol - 40 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 240) {
    output.style.left = vol - 45 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 430) {
    output.style.left = vol - 50 + 'px';
  }
  if (output.value > 470) {
    output.style.left = vol - 55 + 'px';
  }

  // Clear any existing timer and create a new one to print the value
  clearTimeout(outputUpdate.timerId);
  outputUpdate.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(vol);
  }, 500);
}
// Initialize the timerId property to 0
outputUpdate.timerId = 0;
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <output for="fader" id="volume">0</output>
  <input type="range" id="fader" min="0" max="600" value="0" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I will read more about timer

Answer (score 2):

If you update the HTML to wrap your `<input>` and `<output>` in a `<form>`, the `input` and `change` listeners will allow you to watch for changes and update the value of the output as the slider is moved, but only log the value once the slider is no longer being adjusted.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const volumeFader = document.getElementById("volume");
const volumeOutput = document.querySelector("output[for='volume']");

function updateOutput() {
  volumeOutput.value = volumeFader.value;
}

function logValue() {
  console.log(volumeOutput.value);
}

form.addEventListener("input", updateOutput);

form.addEventListener("change", logValue);
```

```html
<form>
  <output for="volume">0</output>
  <input type="range" id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
</form>
```